# pass value from form to modal in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

```
<a href="" data-toggle="modal" class="update_pic" data_id = "$id" data-target="#update-modal"><img height="100px" width="100px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['pestImage'] ).'"/><a/></td>';
echo"<td>$imagedesc $id</td>";
echo"<td>$pestname</td>";
echo"<td>$pesticide</td>";
echo"<td>
<form action='editpest.php?id=$id' method='POST'>
<button  data-toggle='modal' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block' data-target='#update-modal'>Edit</button>
<br/>
<form action='../php/deletepest.php?id=$id' method='POST'>
    <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block'>Delete</button>
</form>
</td>";
echo'</tr>';

<div id="update-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h1 class="modal-title">Update Picture Pest</h1>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<?php echo" <form action='../php/updateImage2.php?id=$id' method='POST'>;"?>
<div style="position:relative;">
<div class="input-group image-preview">
    <input type="text" class="form-control image-preview-filename" disabled="disabled"> <!-- don't give a name === doesn't send on POST/GET -->
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <!-- image-preview-clear button -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default image-preview-clear" style="display:none;">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Clear
        </button>
    <!-- image-preview-input -->
    <div class="btn btn-default image-preview-input">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
            <span class="image-preview-input-title">Browse</span>
            <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" name="input-file-preview"/> <!-- rename it -->

    </div>
    </span>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-7.5">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Update Picture</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Hi I want to pass the value of $id retrieved from the database to the modal, so I can use it as a Where Clause when I Update the Image.

This is my first question hope somebody will answer

Comment: Please consider to fix the code format.

Comment: Ok I will watch the question of other to know the right format.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <a href="" data-toggle="modal" class="update_pic" data_id = "$id" data-target="#update-modal">
            <img height="100px" width="100px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['pestImage'] ).'"/>
        <a/>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $imagedesc.''.$id;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $pestname;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $pesticide;?></td>
    <td>
        <a class='editClass' href="#form_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?echo $id;?>">
                Edit
        </a>
        <form action='../php/deletepest.php?id=$id' method='POST'>
            <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block'>Delete</button>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
$('.editClass').click(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({url:"editpest.php?id="+id,cache:false,success:function(result){
        $(".modal-content").html(result);
    }});
});
</script>
```

**footer** (Place this code in footer or below your `<table></table>`)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="form_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**editpest.php**

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
// Now, write your query here
?>

<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <h4 class="modal-title">Update</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    .
    .
    <?php echo "Id: ".$id;?>
    .
    .   
   // Write code here to update

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I get a lot of idea from your code sir .,

Comment: If you think this answer helped you. Please tick this answer as correct answer. As, it will help other user to find it easily. Thanks @JersonBabieraGevera. *Glad to help* `:)`